# Insert quilljs markers instead of particular occurrences in string

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I use primeng editor based on quilljs and struggling with modification of particular occurrences in string with custom markers. I have string like this:

```
User data {{userName}} - {{lastName}}. Topic {{title}} and date: {{occurredDate}}
```

And I'm trying to achieve this result:

[image]

However quill puts the whole string inside custom blot and result looks next:

[image]

This is my code for custom blot:

```
declare var Quill: any;
const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/embed');

export class Variable extends BlockEmbed {

  static create(value: any) {
    const node = super.create(typeof value === 'object' ? value.text : value);
    node.innerText = typeof value === 'object' ? value.text : value;
    node.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
    return node;
  }

  static value(node) {
    return {
      style: node.getAttribute('contenteditable'),
      text: node.innerText
    };
  }

}

Variable['blotName'] = 'marker';
Variable['className'] = 'marker';
Variable['tagName'] = 'span';

Quill.register('formats/marker', Variable);
```

And this is my function to modify in string

```
 initNotification() {

    if (this.form.valid) {

        this.quill = this.editorComponent.getQuill();

        const delta = this.quill.getContents();

        const marker = function (string) {
          string = string
            .replace(/{{/g, ' ')
            .replace(/}}/g, ' ')

          return {
            marker: {
              style: 'false',
              text: string
            }
          }
        };

        const breaker = {
          insert: '\n'
        };

        const checkDelta = function (ops) {
          ops.forEach( (obj, index, array) => {
            if (!obj.insert.hasOwnProperty('marker') && obj.insert.match(/{{(.*)}}/g)) {
              if (obj.insert.match(/[^\r\n]+/g)) {
                obj.insert = marker(obj.insert);
                array.splice(index + 1, 0, breaker);
                checkDelta(array)
              } else {
                obj.insert = marker(obj.insert);
              }
            }
          });
        };

        checkDelta(delta.ops);

        this.quill.setContents(delta);
        this.quill.update('user');
      }
    }
```

So could somebody help me to find where my mistake is? I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-workaround-guqqxn?file=app/calendar/calendar.component.ts). Unfortunately I couldn't force it to work.

**EDITED**

After some investigation I have found that blot already getting the whole string, that's why the quill applies this string as blot. Also I have found that the problem exactly in this function:

```
 const checkDelta = function (ops) {
          ops.forEach( (obj, index, array) => {
            if (!obj.insert.hasOwnProperty('marker') && obj.insert.match(/{{(.*)}}/g)) {
              if (obj.insert.match(/[^\r\n]+/g)) {

                console.log(obj.insert) // User data {{userFirstname}} -{{userLastname}} . Topic {{title}} . Date: {{occuredAt}}

                obj.insert = marker(obj.insert);

// return marker = {style: false, text: User data userFirstname - userLastname . Topic title . Date: occuredAt}
                array.splice(index + 1, 0, breaker);
                checkDelta(array)
              } else {
                console.log(obj.insert) 

                obj.insert = marker(obj.insert);
              }
            }
          });
        };
```

Comment: It could possibly be easier to resolve this if there would be a way to replicate the problem - a plunk, stackblitz, etc.

Comment: @estus check please my updated post

Answer (score 0):

So in the end of this story, I found out that it is way easier just to replace these curly brackets on span tags right from my code, because quill sees matches and do all other stuff by itself

my working code below:

```
let text = User data {{userName}} - {{lastName}}. Topic {{title}} and date: {{occurredDate}} 

text = text
         .replace(/{{/g, '<span class="marker" contenteditable="false">')
         .replace(/}}/g, '</span>')
```

Also I have changed `node.innerText` to `node.textContent`, because quill adds additional span tag inside and because of this reason sometimes innerText returns empty value.

```
    declare var Quill: any;
const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/embed');

export class Variable extends BlockEmbed {

  static create(value: any) {
    const node = super.create(typeof value === 'object' ? value.text : value);
    node.innerText = typeof value === 'object' ? value.text : value;
    node.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
    return node;
  }

  static value(node) {
    return {
      style: node.getAttribute('contenteditable'),
      text: node.textContent
    };
  }

}

Variable['blotName'] = 'marker';
Variable['className'] = 'marker';
Variable['tagName'] = 'span';

Quill.register('formats/marker', Variable);
```

Also I completely removed code from function initNotification

```
initNotification() {

    if (this.form.valid) {

        this.quill = this.editorComponent.getQuill();

      }
    }
```